# pass argument to docker compose service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command-line-arguments

I have docker compose defied with 2 service,
I need 1st to start with `--dev` command line option,
but I cannot find this in file format spec. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  polkadot:
    image: parity/polkadot:latest
    command: --dev
    ports:
      - "9944:9944"
  sidecar:
    image: parity/substrate-api-sidecar:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

running with `docker-compose up`

---

For comparison, when simply running docker adding `--dev` is straightforward:
`docker run --rm -it -p 9944:9944 parity/polkadot:latest --dev`

But how to within docker-compose file?

Comment: You have the `command:` syntax right, but the `docker run --rm -it` options generally imply you want a "one-off" container with console interaction, and Compose doesn't support that as well as long-running non-interactive containers.  Does the `docker-compose.yml` file you show work; what do the two invocations do differently?

Comment: I have updated question, those are 2 ways to start: docker and docker-compose.
The problem is with docker-compose way.

Comment: I've copied your docker-compose.yml example and started it with `docker-compose up`. I see the following entry as the first line in the logs: `polkadot_1  | 2021-09-16 14:29:05 Running in --dev mode, RPC CORS has been disabled.`. Do you expect a different behavior?

Comment: Indeed, that version of `docker-compose.yml` already did work partly. The final version is in answer below. Some how I was starting with `args:` instead of `command:`, and that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`command:` is the right way to go

It is possible to pass many arguments as:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  polkadot:
    container_name: polkadotdev
    image: parity/polkadot:latest
    ports:
          #- 30333:30333 # p2p port
          - 9933:9933 # rpc port
          - 9944:9944 # ws port
    command: [
        "--dev",
        "--name", "polkadotdevnode",
        "--ws-external",
        "--rpc-external",
        "--rpc-cors", "all"
    ]
  sidecar:
    container_name: sidecardev
    image: parity/substrate-api-sidecar:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SAS_SUBSTRATE_WS_URL: ws://polkadot:9944
```